# how to define implicit casting operator

Tags: c++

I have Classes A, B. B derives from A with protected, so to enable implicit casting from B to A, I have added casting operator, but I get error when using it implicitly (everything ok when using it explicitly).

How to make this code work??

```
class A
{
public:
  int a;
};


class B : protected A {
public:
  int b;
  operator const A&()const { return *this; }
};

B b;
const A& a = b; // ERROR: error C2243: 'type cast' : conversion from 'const b *' to 'const A &' exists, but is inaccessible
```

How to make the casting implicit?

Comment: Why don't you just make the inheritance public?

Comment: because I want to disable some functions from the user. Therefore I enable casting to const reference

Comment: What on earth is `a&` ?

Comment: GCC gives a warning that sheds some light on why this cannot work: *" warning: conversion to a reference to a base class will never use a type conversion operator"*

Comment: *because I want to disable some functions from the user.* That is **so** absurd... how are you disabling anything if you allow the user to upcast anyway? The user can do exactly the same as if inheritance was public, only in a way that is more painful for her (and you, given the issues that lead to the question).

Comment: There is no such thing as an implicit cast. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion, so it is **always** explicit. Some conversions can be done **without** a cast; they are **implicit** conversions.

Answer (score 2):

The conversion operator you provided is already *implicit*. The problem you face is that the compiler is seeing two different conversion sequences from `B` to `const A&`, the derived-to-base reference and your user provided conversion. There is an ordering on conversions, and the derived-to-base conversion is considered better than any user provided conversion, so your `operator const A&() const` will not be chosen.

Just make inheritance public. You are trying to build a convoluted design that provides no benefit whatsoever. What do you want to obtain by making inheritance *protected*? Avoid upcasts? Why are you attempting to provide the same conversion anyway? Do you intend on only allowing half of the interface (the `const` part)? Then you are not following LSP, since your derived object cannot be used as a base...

Comment: The important point here is that all overload resolution takes place without considering access.  Only once the overload resolution has finished does the compiler look at the access, and emit an error if the chosen function is not accessible.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I don't think there is *overload resolution* taking place here. This is just a conversion from an lvalue to derived to a const reference to base. Other than that, the comment is right on: access specifiers are always checked at the end, so they won't drive the decisions as to what path to take. -- Well, to be precise in C++11 access specifiers *can* drive the compiler in SFINAE contexts

Comment: The initialization of `const A& a` is actually resolved by overload resolution, which chooses the best conversion sequence to get from `b` to `const A&`. It's not what the typical programmer would call overload resolution, but the standard doesn't see a difference (and neither do compilers).

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the type conversion operator is defined in B, so it is not available for objects of type A. What you are trying to do is not possible in C++. This is because, the 'this' pointer is a constant pointer.
So, if you try writing the following code within the body of A, it will not work:
`A(B* b)
{
this = b;//error, 'this' pointer is a constant pointer.
}`

In other words, you cannot implicitly make a reference of type A refer to a B type object. At best, you can try a reinterpret cast and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

OK - so I have choosen another design - to use composition instead of inheritance. This way I can define an instance A which is protected

```
class B {
protected:
  A a;
public
  operator const A&()const { return a; }
};

B b;
const A& a = b;
```